# Why isn’t Jing picking up xml:id for XInclude?

Tags: xml, relaxng, xinclude, jing

Given the following files

a.rnc:

```
start = a
a = element a { b }
b = element b {
  attribute xml:id { xsd:ID }?,
  attribute xml:base { xsd:ID }?,
  empty
}
```

a.xml:

```
<a xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <xi:include href="b.xml" xpointer="element(bid)"/>
</a>
```

b.xml:

```
<a><b xml:id="bid"/></a>
```

Why is Jing reporting

```
a.xml:1:97: warning: Include operation failed, reverting to fallback. Resource error reading file as XML (href='b.xml'). Reason: XPointer resolution unsuccessful.
a.xml:1:97: fatal: An 'include' failed, and no 'fallback' element was found.
```

when run as

```
java -Dorg.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration=org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeParserConfiguration -jar jing.jar -c a.rnc a.xml
```

?

If I change the xpointer attribute to `element(/1/1)` it passes.

This is with the 20091111 of Jing with xercesImpl.jar in the same directory as jing.jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Xerces doesn’t support xml:id in a way that makes this possible.  A more detailed explanation is available [on the rng-users mailing list](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rng-users/message/1333).